KVM switch with TrueNAS-Scale/Debian wireless keyboard/mouse not working
My keyboard/mouse does not work after switching KVM from Windows to TrueNAS/Debian Linux.

CKlau-64Hua, single-monitor, 4-Port KVM switch,
HDMI monitor, USB-A keyboard, USB-A mouse,
Cables with single USB-A for keyboard/mouse.
Logitech K360 wireless keyboard, dongle connected to KVM.
Logitech M215 wireless mouse, dongle connected to KVM.
Two Windows systems (7 and 10).
TrueNAS-Scale 24.10.0.2 installed on Gigabyte B360M-D3H-GSM MOBO.

I can switch from any machine to a Windows machine and have no trouble. When in the Gigabyte BIOS, switching from Windows to TrueNAS works fine, also, so this problem is not about the hardware.
After TrueNAS boots, when I switch from Windows, the monitor works fine but the mouse and keyboard don't. Hitting reset on the KVM makes no difference. Replugging the keyboard/mouse dongles in the KVM fixes the problem, but I must do it every time I switch to TrueNAS.
Does anyone know a solution that will reconnect TrueNAS/Debian to the keyboard/mouse after switch?
